# py2app launch error when packaging project

Tags: deployment, pycharm, py2app

I am trying to turn my pycharm project into an app that can run on mac, but when I try with py2app, I get a message that the launch failed and I should go to the website for instructions.

I read all of the fixes on the website and some I wasn't able to understand and others didn't seem right for the issue. This issue is happening both when I create an alias and when I create the app normally. I am not sure if I have passed in the right values for DATA_FILES, I have those four pngs which are used in my code but I'm not sure what is supposed to be in place of 'pngs' as the pngs are in the same file as all of my .py files. I have also tried making `argv_emulation` **True** and **False**. When I run it there is no errors shown in the terminal and instead it just says "Done!" I also tried opening the app manually through terminal but it still fails. [my setup.py code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wnrEy.png)